# Grid invoices by order status

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, invoice

I've created a grid to list the invoices in my store and make decisions from it, but there are some invoices that the order that generated it is with status canceled or delivered. I need to list only the invoices that the base order is with the status processing.

My collection:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
            ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
            ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
            ->addFieldToSelect('order_id')
            ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
            ->addFieldToSelect('order_increment_id')
            ->addFieldToSelect('order_created_at')
            ->addFieldToSelect('state')
            ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
            ->addFieldToSelect('base_grand_total')
            ->addFieldToSelect('store_currency_code')
            ->addFieldToSelect('base_currency_code')
            ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
            ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name')
        ;
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

How to add filter by order status?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it like this:

```
$order_status = "processing";
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass())
        ->addFieldToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_increment_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('state')
        ->addFieldToSelect('grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('base_grand_total')
        ->addFieldToSelect('store_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('base_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('order_currency_code')
        ->addFieldToSelect('billing_name');

    $collection->getSelect()->join( array('order'=> 'sales_flat_order'), 'order.entity_id = main_table.order_id', array('order.status'))
        ->where("order.status = ?", $order_status);
```